# Save query results from presto without quotes using Linux

Tags: presto

I am using a presto Db in Linux environment. When I wish to save my query results into a file it is saved with quotes around them.

lets say I run:

```
    presto-cli --schema default --catalog hive --execute "select distinct(cust)    from sales" > results.txt
```

and the results are saved like so:

```
    "David B"
```

I use sed 's/\"//g' to remove the quotes later on but I wonder if there is a way around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default output format is `CSV`. You can use `TSV` (tab-separated values) which won't have quotes surrounding the fields:

```
presto --output-format TSV --execute "SELECT ..."
```

If you want to turn the tabs into commas (or another character), you can pipe the result through the standard UNIX `tr` command:

```
presto ... | tr '\t' ','
```

Note that the `TSV` output format uses C-style escaping for fields, so if your data has a tab, newline, backslash, etc., you'll see things like `\n` or `\\` in the output.